# Using OSG's osgViewerQt example with Qt signals/slots

Tags: c++, qt4, signals-slots, openscenegraph

I have already posted this in the OSG mailing list, but the mailing list seems to be a bit slow.

Anyway, I'm trying to modify the [osgViewerQt example](http://www.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg/browser/OpenSceneGraph/trunk/examples/osgviewerQt/osgviewerQt.cpp) by adding a new class of my
own that will contain the viewer. The design is:

- **wrapper.h**: Defines class *Wrapper*. It inherits from
  *QMainWindow* and has a
  *QDockWidget* where the *ViewerWidget* will be attached.
- **viewer.h**: Defines *ViewerWidget* class. It's the class from the
  example, with a few mods by me.
- **prueba_qt.cpp**: Main function and where a QApplication is created. A Wrapper object is
  created here.

The project compiles, but when I execute it, I get an error:

```
QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice*
```

If I remove the *Q_OBJECT* line, the *signal* and the *slot* from
*wrapper.h* and compile the files from the terminal using

```
g++ -IE:/osg-3.0.1/install/include -LE:/osg-3.0.1/install/bin -IC:/Qt64/4.8/include -LC:/Qt64/4.8/bin -losgViewer -lOpenThreads -losgDB -losg -losgGA -losgQt -lQtCore4 -lQtGui4 prueba_qt.cpp
```

I can execute the app.

Can you please tell me what can I do to make this work? I've struggling all
morning but couldn't find the solution.

Thanks for your time!

PS: SO is Windows 7 64 bits # MingW compiler # Qt 4.8 # OSG 3.0.1

PS2: Here're the files I used in this project, including the *pro* file from qmake:

**wrapper.h**

```
    #ifndef Wrapper_hpp
    #define Wrapper_hpp

    #include "viewer.h"
    #include <QtGui/QMainWindow>
    #include <QtGui/QDockWidget>

    class Wrapper: public QMainWindow {
     Q_OBJECT
    private:
      ViewerWidget* view;
      QDockWidget* dock;
    public:
      Wrapper(void) {
        view = new ViewerWidget();
        dock = new QDockWidget;
        dock->setWidget( view );
        dock->setGeometry( 100, 100, 800, 600 );
        dock->setAllowedAreas(Qt::RightDockWidgetArea);
        addDockWidget(Qt::RightDockWidgetArea, dock);
        dock->show();
      }
      void Do(void) { view->Do(); }
      void Add(void) { view->Add(); }
      virtual ~Wrapper(void) {}
      public slots:
        void MySlot(void) {}
      signals:
        void MySignal(void);
    };
    #endif
```

**wrapper.cpp**

(This exists only because I read in the Qt forum that *moc* can only parse *cpp* files and thus one is needed for the signal/slot mechanism.)

```
    #include "wrapper.h"

    Wrapper::Wrapper(void) {
        view = new ViewerWidget();
    //    view->setGeometry( 100, 100, 800, 600 );
        dock = new QDockWidget;
        dock->setWidget( view );
        dock->setGeometry( 100, 100, 800, 600 );
        dock->setAllowedAreas(Qt::RightDockWidgetArea);
        addDockWidget(Qt::RightDockWidgetArea, dock);
        dock->show();
    }
```

**prueba_qt.cpp**

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include "wrapper.h"

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
    osg::ArgumentParser arguments(&argc, argv);
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Wrapper wrap;
    wrap.resize(800,600);
    wrap.setWindowTitle("Cow");
    wrap.showNormal();
    wrap.Do();    
    return app.exec();
}
```

**prueba_qt.pro**

```
    ######################################################################
    # Automatically generated by qmake (2.01a) mar 12. mar 13:45:28 2013
    ######################################################################
    QT += core gui
    TEMPLATE = app
    TARGET = 
    DEPENDPATH += .
    INCLUDEPATH += . E:/osg-3.0.1/install/include
    LIBS += -LE:/osg-3.0.1/install/bin -losg -lOpenThreads -losgDB -losgGA -losgQt -losgViewer

    # Input
    HEADERS += viewer.h wrapper.h
    SOURCES += prueba_qt.cpp wrapper.cpp
```

**viewer.h:** This is quite big, so I uploaded it to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/4FPTfGkL)

**EDIT #1**

I have set *OSG_NOTIFY_LEVEL* to *DEBUG_INFO* and got [this](http://pastebin.com/xvqKV3eG) humongous output. The line with the error is:

```
FindFileInPath() : trying C:\cygwin\bin\osgPlugQWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice
```

**EDIT #2**

The signal and slot were missing in the code. I have just added them to *wrapper.h* along with the call to *Q_OBJECT*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little nap, I revised again the libraries used in the project. The problem was that some of those libraries were in debug mode and some in release mode. When using signals and slots, `moc` went crazy.

After building `OSG` debug libraries, I tried again my little example and worked.

So it's done!